# Odoo encoding issue

Tags: python, odoo

I install odoo 11 on Ubuntu by docker, it run perfectly

But when I change to Vietnamese (Unicode), I got blank page issue.[image][image]
Anyone have experience about this, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's an issue that's already been resolved in the Odoo sources, but the docker image hasn't been updated.

https://github.com/odoo/docker/issues/130